# Как расчитать плавное уменьшение иконки при отдалении от неё?

Tags: алгоритм

Ищу пример расчета плавного изменения размера иконки при отдалении от объекта).

Что мы имеем:

0 - расстояние (начало просмотра)

2000 - расстояние (максимальная отдалённость)

1 - размер иконки при расстояние - 0 (начало просмотра)

0.3 - размер иконки при максимальном отдалении 2000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно это делается функцией линейной интерполяции `lerp`:

```
function lerp(a, b, f: single): single;
Result = a + (b - a) * f;
```

где `a` и `b` это границы, а `f` - коэффициент внутри этих границ от 0 до 1.

что в вашем случае превращается в

```
a = 1;
b = 0.3;
f = currentDistance / 2000;
```

для расстояния `currentDistance = 200`

```
Result = 1 + (0.3 - 1) * (200 / 2000); // 0.93
```

для расстояния `currentDistance = 1800`

```
Result = 1 + (0.3 - 1) * (1800 / 2000); // 0.37
```

---

Имея `lerp`, легко сделать его нелинейным, например через `f = sin(f)` или `f = f * f` или `f = sqrt(f)`.

Answer (score 0):

Например, линейная зависимость, если не обращать внимание на возможную физическую сущность:

```
Size = 1.0 - 0.7*distance/2000
```

Или чуть ближе к ней: берём формулу (упрощённая формула *(считаем tg(x)~x)* для видимого размера)

```
Size = k/(k+distance)
```

и находим `k`, которое обеспечивает верное значение при макс. дальности, получается

```
Size = 857.14286 / (857.14286 + distance)
```

Comment: Уточните плиз, что за волшебное число `857.14286` ?

Comment: @Kromster Коэффициент, обеспечивающий нужные результаты при нуле и 2000, численно это 600/0.7

Comment: Хардкод .. такое себе )

Comment: size = k/(k+distance) решаем для крайних случаев, получаем k

Comment: Лучше эти уточнения в ответ добавить